Bounds for Dirichlet L-functions
Let $L$ denote a Dirichlet L-function attached to the primitive character $\chi$. What are the best known bounds for $L(\sigma+it, \chi)$?
PS: For $L=\zeta$ and $0\leq\sigma\leq 1$, i'm aware of a result of Heath-Brown (Theorem 1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.04493) that $\zeta(\sigma+it) \ll t^{\frac{1}{2}(1-\sigma)^{3/2}+\varepsilon}$ (and maybe there could be something sharper than this).

Do you want a bound in the $t$-aspect only, or also in the conductor aspect? Are you interested in the range $\sigma\approx 1/2$, or in the range $\sigma\approx 1$?

Preferrably in both the $t$ and conductor aspect for $0\leq \sigma \leq 1$, in the spirit of Heath-Brown's aforementioned result.

Heath-Brown's result is only good when $\sigma$ is close to $1$. For $\sigma$ away from $1$, there are better bounds.

@GHfromMO, you're right, but i would prefer something that covers the entire critical strip. Anyway, Heath-brown is sufficient form my purposes. By the way, can you please share a reference for $L(\sigma+it, \chi) \ll (1+q|t|)^{0.25+\varepsilon}$? I vaguely recall coming across it in GLH literature, but can't recall the exact paper/book.

The state of the art is Petrow-Young's Weyl-strength subconvex bound $L(1/2 + it,\chi) \ll_{\varepsilon} (q(|t| + 1))^{1/6 + \varepsilon}$, which is then coupled with the Phragmen-Lindelof convexity principle to obtain bounds for $L(\sigma + it,\chi)$ for all $\sigma \in [0,1]$.

@Q_p The convexity bound (i.e. the exponent $1/4+\varepsilon$) follows quickly from the functional equation and the Phragmén-Lindelöf convexity principle. Alternatively, it follows quickly from the approximate functional equation. You can find a more general version (applying to more $L$-functions) in Iwaniec-Kowalski's book "Analytic number theory".

Do you need a bound for which the exponent goes to $0$ faster than linearly as $\sigma-1\to 0^-$?

@HAHelfgott I included such a bound in my response. I believe the bounds in my response are the state-of-the-art.

@GHfromMO Ah, good call.

As Peter Humphries said in a comment, the best known bound for $\sigma=1/2$ (applying to all $\chi$) is due to Petrow and Young:
$$L(1/2 + it,\chi) \ll_{\varepsilon} (q(|t| + 1))^{1/6 + \varepsilon}.$$
This can be coupled with the Phragmén-Lindelöf convexity principle to obtain a good bound for all $\sigma\in[0,1]$. For $\sigma\approx 1$ (hence also for $\sigma\approx 0$) there are better bounds available. For example, Lemma 5.1 in Tanmay Khale's recent paper (arXiv version here) implies for $|t|\geq 3$ and $1/2\leq\sigma\leq 1$ that
$$    |L(\sigma+it,\chi)| \leq  76.2 q^{1-\sigma}|t|^{4.45(1-\sigma)^{3/2}}(\log |t|)^{2/3} + 1.92 \frac{q^{1-\sigma}-1}{1-\sigma}.
$$
Here $\chi$ is any Dirichlet character of modulus $q\geq 3$.

thank you! I would be glad if you can also comment on the validity of my answer to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/a/469741/480516.

@Q_p Sorry, I don't have time to check that answer carefully. I trust it is okay though, there are many knowledgeable readers on this site.
